# SQL not ordering by descending with php query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT - AS -
         FROM -
         WHERE ID = '".$id."'
         ORDER BY 'PRIMARY' DESC
         LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit."";
```

However, for some reason the query is always returned in ascending order, even though I have told it to order by descending.

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. When I do the query via phpMyAdmin, it returns correctly, but the PHP query is not listing the results in descending order.

note: the -'s in the query are names from my database that I have snipped. They are filled with the correct names in the actual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks instead of single quotes near `PRIMARY`

```
$query = "SELECT - AS -
         FROM -
         WHERE ID = '".$id."'
         ORDER BY `PRIMARY` DESC
         LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit."";
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I forgot about backticks.

Comment: No problem. The rule of thumb is backticks (`) around column names, and single quotes (') around strings.

Answer (score 2):

your query isn't actually ordered at all
you are ordering by the constant string `PRIMARY` whis going to be equal for all the rows.

Comment: Ahhh wasn't sure if he had used PRIMARY as column name placeholder or not.

Answer (score 2):

you are sorting the results by a constant value `'PRIMARY'` (which is always the same)
you want to sort by a column, so you need to specify the column, for example

```
ORDER BY column1
```

if the column name is `column1` 
you can't use PRIMARY like this, only if it's a column name. in this case you would write

```
ORDER BY `PRIMARY`
```

as `PRIMARY` is a mysql keyword (for primary key uses)

notice that

```
`PRIMARY`
```

is different from

```
'PRIMARY'
```

which is a constant value

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried echoing out the query to make sure it matches the query you put into phpmyadmin

Comment: he had that, the query was working. just the sorting didn't work because of the single quotes.

Comment: @StefanN - That's why I asked if he echoed it out through php this tends to out the mistake it's self as I'm sure you're aware. I was going to the whole give a man a fish vs teach a man to fish

Comment: :-) i understand, it seems more like a mysql issue, not php. he obviously echoed the query, as he posted it here